# How to remove the bottom white space of UIView in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am new in iOS development and i am facing an issue with layout in storyboard.

I created a UIViewController and added a Container. Inside this container i created my layout, see image below:
[storyboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8YlB.png)

However when i run my project there is a white space below my layout. I run out of ideas to fix this
[Layout in the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqWGv.png)

To call my viewController that contains the Container i used:

```
let postView = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InfoPostView") as! InformationPostingViewController
        presentViewController(postView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you add the related code

Comment: I don't implement anything yet in the viewcontroller that contains the Container, i just present it using the presentViewController

Comment: no constraints are being applied, that is why the button is being chopped off,  it is probably using the default 600x600 layout or whatever, so the view controller has no idea how to apply the view to the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use constraints to make sure the container view fills up the whole screen, regardless of the screen's dimensions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, I missed the constraints
Now it is working :)

Comment: No problem. We all need to start somewhere! :)